# Link to Flask static files with url_for

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

How do you use `url_for` in Flask to reference a file in a folder?  For example, I have some static files in the `static` folder, some of which may be in subfolders such as `static/bootstrap`.

When I try to serve a file from `static/bootstrap`, I get an error.

```
 <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static/bootstrap', filename='bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

I can reference files that aren't in subfolders with this, which works.

```
 <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

What is the correct way to reference static files with `url_for`?  How do I use `url_for` to generate urls to static files at any level?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

You have by default the [`static` endpoint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files) for static files. Also [`Flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask) application has the following arguments:

`static_url_path`: can be used to specify a different path for the static files on the web. Defaults to the name of the `static_folder` folder.

`static_folder`: the folder with static files that should be served at `static_url_path`. Defaults to the 'static' folder in the root path of the application.

It means that the `filename` argument will take a relative path to your file in `static_folder` and convert it to a relative path combined with `static_url_default`:

```
url_for('static', filename='path/to/file')
```

will convert the file path from `static_folder/path/to/file` to the url path `static_url_default/path/to/file`.

So if you want to get files from the `static/bootstrap` folder you use this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

Which will be converted to (using default settings):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Also look at [`url_for` documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.url_for).

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had special instruction into nginx configuration file:

```
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
    }
```

All clients have received '404' because nginx nothing known about Flask.

The primary configuration file is `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` on Linux. It may be similar on Windows.

Comment: Hard-coding a list of file extensions like that seems like it will create surprises and toil to maintain. Probably better to use something that explicitly mentions the `/static/` path prefix and then serves whatever file the user requests from within that static directory. Also ensure you [avoid common nginx errors with that setup](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#using-the-try-files-uri-directive-with-alias).