# raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method) for image path

Tags: python, path, flask

I am trying to add the image to my page:

```
<td>
     <img src="{{ url_for('images', filename='test.png') }}">Test
 </td>
```

But I am getting this error when I run my flask server:

```
raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method)
BuildError: ('images', {'filename': 'test.png'}, None)
```

I have added `test.png` in `images` directory.

Comment: Do you have a route named 'images'? Or did you make images a static path? You need to post more code from your application, at least all the @app.route lines and how you're instantiating the Flask object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flask url\_for Referencing Static Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351826/flask-url-for-referencing-static-files)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your images folder is not inside the static folder. If you move it inside your static folder and reference it as such

```
{{url_for('static',filename='images/test.png')}}
```

it should work