# Slick carrousel not working in Flask

Tags: python, css, flask

I have the Slick-Carrousel package open on my desktop.  When I run the package on my desktop, it works.  But when I copy and paste Slick into my Flask templates directory and modify my controller to load the index file, all the links are broken.  I also extracted to the root of my program, and the links are still broken.

I can get limited functionality by using jsdeliver.net to repair the CSS links, but I don't know how to link all the different file types in the fonts category, which don't show up as 404s in the console.

The files can be found here:
http://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/jquery.slick

To be specific, how do I link the gif, eot, svg, ttf, and woff files?

Edit: here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Slick Playground</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick-theme.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 100px auto;
    }

    .slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }

    .slick-slide img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
        color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <section class="regular slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="center slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=7">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=8">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=9">
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="variable slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=6">
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="./slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
      $(".regular").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
      $(".center").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        centerMode: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
      $(".variable").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        variableWidth: true
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is a screenshot of my file structure:

[image]

Edit: This post was marked as a duplicate of this question: [Link to Flask static files with url_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351826/link-to-flask-static-files-with-url-for)

But I have a different problem.  I am not trying to link individual files using URL-for.  I am trying to link an entire directory so the javascript can find all the files it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to write:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/slick/slick.css">
```

adding the static directory.  Flask files need to go in the static directory, and I needed to reflect this change in the link.