# Upload images from file system to html page

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying do develop a very simple web app using flask, following the example from this [link](https://pythonspot.com/flask-web-app-with-python/).

My problem is: I want to show images from my file system in that page but it seems like browsers are protected against that. I have to use something like:

```
<img src="http://aMessyURL.png">
```

Instead of being able to use something like:

```
<img src="images/myImageName.png">
```

So, I can I (dynamically) show images from my file system?

Comment: did you read [Flask Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files) section for static files? For more you can read [Link to Flask static files with url_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351826/link-to-flask-static-files-with-url-for)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it when hosting a simple server:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

This should at least allow you to load files in the same folder as your code.

Answer (score 0):

Flask interprets `<img src="images/myImageName.png">` as:

app/images/myImageName.png

Normally, Flask projects have a static folder inside app (app/static) which contains your CSS, JS and images. You can either render them like above or use url_for:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/favicon.png') }}">
```

Which renders fully as:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/img/favicon.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to specify static root path and then use code in html below

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
```

In HTML

```
<img src="/static/images/myImageName.png">
```