# Flask unable to resolve static files after moving app.py and static folder

Tags: python, html, flask

I am packaging up my Flask app and I am unable to resolve static URLs after migrating the app.py into the module ship_comm even though it is picking up the new templates path when I change the root_folder. Here is my structure:

```
├── README.md 
├── requirements.txt 
├── setup.py 
└── ship_comm
    ├── app.py
    ├── config.py
    ├── database.py
    ├── db_models.py
    ├── devices.py
    ├── replay.py
    ├── router.py
    ├── routing.db
    ├── static
    │   ├── css
    │   │   └── main.css
    │   └── img
    │       ├── captain-ai-logo-small.png
    │       ├── captain-ai-logo-square.png
    │       ├── favicon.ico
    │       └── screenshot.png
    └── templates
        ├── devices.html
        ├── home.html
        ├── layout.html
        ├── messages.html
        ├── new_route.html
        ├── new_serial.html
        ├── new_udp.html
        └── routes.html
```

And here is my initialization of the Flask app

`app = Flask(__name__, root_path='ship_comm')`

This fixed my issue with TemplateNotFound error, but still it's not able to find the static folder, even though it should be able to find it in the root_path right? I have tried explicitly stating `static_folder='ship_comm/static'` and `static_folder='static'` but that also didn't help.

I call the app by using `python -m ship_comm.app`

Here is my layout.html that is now missing the logo:

```
<!doctype html  lang="en">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/favicon.ico') }}">
<title>Ship Comm Router</title>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

<!--- mobile stuff --->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
<div class="container-fluid">
<a href="/"><h1>Ship Comm Router</h1></a>
{%- for category, message in get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
  <p class="flask {{ category }}-flash">{{
    "Error: " if category == 'error' }}{{ message }}</p>
{%- endfor %}
<hr>
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
<hr>
<div id="footer">
    <!--<img width="50px" src="../static/img/captain-ai-logo-small.png"/>-->
    <img width="50px" src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/captain-ai-logo-small.png')}}"/>
    Developed by Captain AI - 2018
</div>
</div>
<!-- <address>Flask and SQLAlchemy powered Serial and UDP Router</address> -->
```

I am using Python 3.6.7 and Flask==1.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`root_path` should be automaticaly calculated. If you want to set it, try to use absolute path (assuming you create the app in `app.py`:

```
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
app = Flask(__name__, root_path=dir_path)
```

Then your static files should be working.

Comment: Nice, that fixes the issue. Does that mean there is a bug in Flask or is that expected behaviour? It's strange that my templates worked but my statics did not.

Comment: It's commented as absolute path in source code: https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L350 so probably you're lucky that templates were working.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar structure to yours and ran into this issue when trying to follow a tutorial to create a Docker container for my small webapp. I eventually want to deploy this container to a QNAP to see if I can host things myself. What worked for me was:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates', static_folder="../static")
```