# Animate.css won't work when loaded localy

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animate.css

I have a flask server which hosts a html file for testing. In the head of this html I want to link to a localy stored animate.min.css file (`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='animate.min.css') }}">` ).
When I open the page I can look in the insepector and see the linked css file (and I can open it) but the style doesn't work (e.g. `<h1 class="animated zoomIn">Index Page</h1>` won't do the animation).
However when I use a file from a CDN (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">`) it works and the effect is be visible.
Why is that? Am I doing something wrong? It's my first time using it so I don't have much experience. Please ask if some information is missing.

Whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='animate.min.css') }}">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">-->
    
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery-3.5.1.min.js') }}"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 class="animated zoomIn">Index Page</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Directory structure:

- Server

  - static

    - animate.min.css
    - jquery-3.5.1.min.js
  - templates

    - index.html
  - server.py

Note:

- The jQuery import is working
- I **can** access the "animate.min.css"-file under "localhost:5000/static/animate.min.css"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351826/link-to-flask-static-files-with-url-for any of this help?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem because I have JS files loaded localy which work. (Sorry, havn't mentioned it in the question)

Comment: Can you add your directory structure?

Comment: Try adding `type="text/css"`

Comment: Did after looking at ur link. Nothing changed.

Comment: Did you check the loading in your console?

Comment: I did. There are no problems or warnings. Not sure if there is an easy way to check if a css file is loaded (other than just using it). I also looked at the network log and there I can see the "animate.min.css" file with the content in the response and a 200 status header.

Comment: Ensure that you are not using an older version!

Comment: I took it directly from the GitHub repository (4.1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if u need a earlier or more current version. Have that issue time to time that only one component gets updated and is now not useable with the other anymore.

Comment: When thanks. Indeed, I need a earlier version. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem (Animate.css won't work when loaded locally).
Worked fine from CDN but not when I had it in a local directory.  I put the CDN link into my browser and copied the entire file to my local folder.  Renamed it animate.css and it worked fine.  The version I copied was 4.1.1.  the version I was using was 3.7.

Thanks to Makoto Niijima.