# How to pass data inside html tags?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

**Please refer to this post where a similar question is already answered**: [Link to Flask static files with url_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351826/link-to-flask-static-files-with-url-for) .

I have a simple `embed` html block that relates to a filepath.

```
<embed src="/static/filename.txt">
```

However the filename changes(the path stays the same) as the content inside file changes time to time. Hence, I am currently passing the `filename` to the html template with the following code(flask)

```
return render_template('view.html', filename = filename )
```

Is there way to pass the file name in to embed html tag? The goal result to be something like this?

```
<embed src="/static/{filename}.txt">
```

where the `{filename}` changes based on passed data from flask.

Any help or suggestion of implementation is appreciated!

Comment: You have to recreate the tag using JavaScript, variables aren't evaluated in HTML.

Comment: Or you have to use PHP if the filename is known at starting website.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
<embed src="/static/{{filename}}.txt">
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! can't believe I missed to try this...Thank you!

Comment: Then you should accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using template strings? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

It allows you to insert a variable inside a string.

Your example would look something like this:

```js
<embed src=`/static/${filename}.txt`>
```

Comment: I tried but I don't think template strings works inside html tags